# Selenium instagram followers throws stale element reference

Tags: java, selenium

I'm in the middle of collecting data for Machine Learning, and I am struggling with scraping one of the social network pages for data. I'm good until the 12th follower, and then it crashes.

The method, driver.findElement(By.xpath... stops working on the 13th element, even though it's scrolling. Could anyone point me to the reason for it not being visible? This is what I came up until now:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Testing {

public static ChromeOptions options;
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    options = new ChromeOptions();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");
}

public static void login() throws Exception {
    String name = "xxxxxx";
    String password = "xxxxxxx";
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(name);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("form")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("See All")));
   driver.get(String.format("https://www.instagram.com/officialrickastley/"));
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("follower")).click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    for (int j = 1; j < 1000; j += 11) {
        System.out.println("j " + j);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[" + (j) + "]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a")));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element);
        actions.perform();
        for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
            System.out.println("user: " + i + " " + driver.findElement(By.xpath(("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[" + (i + j) + "]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a")))
                    .getAttribute("title"));
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    driver.close();
  }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try adding an explicit wait to wait until the element is visible and then perform the required action.

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("ur xpath here")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't locate element that has not been loaded yet